# Why Isshiki Ōtsutsuki can't go back to Konoha when he was sent to another dimension by Boruto?

Tags: boruto

In episode 215 of Boruto the anime, Boruto and Sasuke use a trick to send Isshiki Ōtsutsuki to another dimension so they can fight freely without having to worry about Konoha. But when Isshiki Ōtsutsuki was using Jigen as his vessel, he was able to teleport Naruto to another dimension, so he has dimensional abilities. Also, he has the skill of storing various objects in a pocket dimension so he can bring them to the current dimension he is whenever he wants and use them.

Then, why  Isshiki Ōtsutsuki can't go back to Konoha when he was sent to another dimension by Boruto, if he can send people and things to other dimensions?

Comment: prolly because he knows hed just be followed by naruto and friends so its better to just dewl with them then find kawaki, but this didnt work because of **thou great art** called plot

Answer (score 1):

He can but going back to konoha won't work for him.
He needs to find Kawaki before his lifespan pass out and only Naruto knows where he is. So it would be better if Ishikki would deal with Naruto and kill him, due to which the big threat for Ishikki's plan would be elimited.